# PDO How to make a reusable code structure for return/echo commands?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, reusability

I'm **new** for PDO so I would be glad if you help. For example I have this table:

```
| id   | text                |
| ---- | --------------      |
| 1    | Hello.              |
| 2    | Welcome to my       |
| 3    | website.            |
```

I use PDO to fetch text like this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("select * from texts where id = :id");

$query->execute([ 'id' => 1 ]);
$fetchquery = $query ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $fetchquery['text'];

$query->execute([ 'id' => 2 ]);
$fetchquery = $query ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $fetchquery['text'];

OUTPUT: Hello. Welcome to my...
```

It's hard to write 3 blocks of code for each word. Is there any way that I can do it easier? For example:

```
echo $fetchquery['1']; (only id)
echo $fetchquery['2'];
echo $fetchquery['3'];

OUTPUT: Hello. Welcome to my website.
```

Is there a structure for that kind of usage?

Comment: Why can't you create a function of your own... like `echo fetchTextbyId(1);`

Comment: Or don't limit the selection by ID in the first place, but select _all_ of them - and put them into an array, using the ID as key, so that you can access them via that directly afterwards.

Comment: Just select all rows and iterate over `$query`

Comment: You know enough PHP to pull data from a DB, but you somehow don't know about functions? Hmm.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. Writing a function solved it.

```
function fetch($input) {
   global $db;
   $query = $db->prepare("select id,text from texts where id = :id");
   $query->execute([ 'id' => $input ]);
   $fetchquery= $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $fetchquery['text']; 
}

echo fetch("1");
```